# Strange Output from DS1307 RTC

Tags: rtc

I'm using a DS1307 RTC (https://www.adafruit.com/product/3296) and an Arduino mega microcontroller trying to simply set and read the time of the RTC. However, whenever I try to output anything to the Serial Monitor, I get stuff like this:

[image: Example Output]

The code and the wiring is fairly straightforward which is why I'm confused. I'm just directly attaching the Vcc, GRND, SCL and SDA pins of the clock to the Arduino and using a slightly modified version of the example code as a part of the RTC library Adafruit supplied.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include "RTClib.h"

RTC_DS1307 rtc;

void setup () {
  while (!Serial); // for Leonardo/Micro/Zero

  Serial.begin(57600);
  rtc.begin();

  rtc.adjust(DateTime(2017, 11, 17, 20, 33, 0));


}

void loop () {
    DateTime now = rtc.now();

    Serial.print(now.year(), DEC);
    Serial.print('/');
    Serial.print(now.month(), DEC);
    Serial.print('/');
    Serial.print(now.day(), DEC);
    Serial.print(' ');
    Serial.print(now.hour(), DEC);
    Serial.print(':');
    Serial.print(now.minute(), DEC);
    Serial.print(':');
    Serial.print(now.second(), DEC);
    Serial.println();

    Serial.println();
    delay(1000);
}
```

So I know I'm doing something wrong but I'm not sure what. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a schematic of how you have the DS1307 wired?

Comment: Looks like a baud rate issue. Check your clock speed and settings.

Comment: Set the serial monitor to 57600 and check.

Comment: @ammar.cma In the code above you can see that I did set the serial monitor to 57600

Comment: @Trevor What should I be changing it too exactly?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel like I said in the above posted I literally just have it plugged directly into the SDA, SCL, 5V and Ground pins of the arduino.

Comment: No idea, it depends on the frequency of your micro and what you are connected to.

Comment: I mean not in your code, but in the monitor that you display on : So check on the bottom right on that window, there should the a baud rate that can be set.  COM4 window

Answer (score -1):

Change the baud rate to 57600, it specifies at:
    Serial.begin(57600);

Comment: Thank you for the advice @senpaiscuba. I am new to stackoverflow and did not realize you could edit after posting.